# Asp.net: Excel file uploading does not finish but gives no error message

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I'm having a rather weird problem trying to upload an Excel file and storing it in a SQL server table in an ASP.net App.
The file is not too big: about 2.5 or 3 Mb. 
The problem is that the upload gets "interrupted" after loading some rows, appearently without causing any specific error, since the load process finishes by showing a success message that I'm sending to the client:

> "The process finished successfuly: XXX rows were uploaded from the
>   file".

The problem is that the XXX rows are not all the rows from the file. Depending on how much information there is in each column of the Excel file, the process is only uploading, for instance, 15500 rows from a total of 25000 that the file has. (If there's less information in the Excel file, it can upload, lets say 20000 of the 25000 rows that it may have)... the fact is that the file is not being "completely" uploaded.

I already tried increasing the `"httprequest-maxRequestLength"` value in the web.config, even though the file is not bigger than the default 4Mb file upload that ASP.net has.
The code (vb.net) that I'm using upload and read the file is, basically, this:

```
Dim connection As DbConnection = Nothing
Dim Command As DbCommand = Nothing
Dim ConexionStringExcel As String
Dim dr As DbDataReader
Dim mensajeError as String = ""
Dim ncAdic as Integer = 0
Dim nReg as Integer = 0

'String connection for Excel 2007: for now, I'm not allowing other Excel versions
ConexionStringExcel = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source = " & sNombreArch & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;"

'sNombreArch is the full name of the uploaded file

connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConexionStringExcel)

Command = connection.CreateCommand()

Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + nomHojaArch + "$]"

'---
'lblMensaje is a Label object in the aspx page:
'---
lblMensaje.Visible = False

Try
    'Open the Excel file
    connection.Open()
    'Read file content
    dr = Command.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read
        Try
            'Two first columns of the file are mandatory in my case...
            If Not IsDBNull(dr(0)) And Not IsDBNull(dr(1)) Then
                '---
                'dsTempCargue is a SqlDataSource object in the aspx page
                '---
                dsTempCargue.InsertParameters.Item("idReg").DefaultValue = dr(0)
                dsTempCargue.InsertParameters.Item("nombre").DefaultValue = dr(1)

                For ncAdic = 2 To 10
                    If Not IsDBNull(dr(ncAdic)) Then
                        dsTempCargue.InsertParameters.Item(ncAdic).DefaultValue = dr(ncAdic)
                    Else
                        dsTempCargue.InsertParameters.Item(ncAdic).DefaultValue = DBNull.ToString
                    End if
                Next

                dsTempCargue.Insert()

                                              nReg = nReg + 1
            Else
                mensajeError = "Column A and B of the File cannot be empty"
                Exit While
            End If
        Catch exRead As Exception
            mensajeError = "Error reading the file or saving its content: " & exRead.Message
            Exit While
        End Try             
    End While

    'If there was no error, show success message
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(mensajeError) Then
        mensajeError = "The process finished successfuly. " & nReg.ToString() & " rows were uploaded from the file"
    End IF
Catch ex As Exception
    mensajeError = "Error uploading the file: " & ex.Message        
End Try 

lblMensaje.Text = mensajeError
lblMensaje.Visible = True
```

Why do you think this uploading process is failing to read the entire file???... Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

For the tables that you are storing the rows in, what datatype are the various columns? Perhaps the content of one of the cells is incompatible with the column datatype. Do you have any way of checking?

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your answer... However, I already checked the datatypes of my SQL Table vs. the information from the Excel File and found nothing wrong. The first column of my SQL Table (and the file) is an int column, the rest are strings (varchar)... My App. is always reading fine certaing amount of information: depending on how much information there is in the Excel file, my process uploads less or more rows (please read original question)... I suspect there's some kind of "limit" parameter (other than httprequest-maxRequestLength) that I must configure??. Any other ideas??

Comment: When you upload the same file multiple times, are the same amount of rows inserted?

Comment: Yes, that's right: If upload exactly the same file, the number of inserted rows are always the same... Any clues??... Thanks a lot

Comment: On the first row that is not inserted, how is it different from the last row that was successfully inserted? Also, what do you mean by less Information in the excel file? does that mean less columns?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm really not sure about what could have been the cause of the error, I finally managed to get it working by changing my code to use a Third-party library that I found and that had some good comments, which is available here:

http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

I'm not really sure about what the original problem was and why using this library solved the issue, but It worked. (Perhaps when I have some time I'll try to find more info about this problem I had)

Thanks Patrick for your comments and all for the interest